# Clicking a radio

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I checked the other posts like this but they weren't able to help me. I'm just starting out with Selenium and I'm having trouble clicking a radio button.

This is what is in the inspector.

```
input id="createCreds" name="addUser" aria-required="true" ng-model="formData.newUserType" ng-required="addNewUser.$submitted &amp;&amp; !formData.newUserType" "="" class="ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" aria-checked="true" aria-invalid="false" value="createCreds" type="radio"
```

Here is what I've tried

- Trial 1 :

  ```
  WebElement  userRadioBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("createCreds"));
  userRadioBtn.click();
  ```
- Trial 2 :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="createCreds"]']")).click();
  ```
- Trial 3 :

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.id("createCreds")).click();
  ```
- Trial 4 :

  ```
  input[@value='createCreds']/following-sibling::label
  ```

I was trying to copy this guy around 6 minutes.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKbzW4S2qQ0

I was hoping to find something like Click RadioButton  css=#createCreds or xpath=//*[@id="createCreds"]

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the *Radio Button* as the element is an *Angular* element  you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use either of the following options as follows :

- **cssSelector** :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.ng-valid.ng-valid-required.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse.ng-touched#createCreds"))).click();
  ```
- **xpath** :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched' and @id='createCreds']"))).click();
  ```